# Writing jest for mongodb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am new to javascript.I am working on a fake facebook front-end project in a class project.I am trying to write a test to mock images for my post model where I can store images in my mongodb database. I wanted to know what the best way is the mock my image output to test it has been stored in database. I have my post model code and test so far.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  message: String,
  timestamp: Date,
  // image: Buffer,
});

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('../mongodb_helper');


var Post = require('../../models/post');

describe('Post model', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.collections.posts.drop(() => {
      done();
    });
  });

  it('has a message', () => {
    var post = new Post({ message: 'some message' });
    expect(post.message).toEqual('some message');
  });

  it('can list all posts', (done) => {
    Post.find((err, posts) => {
      expect(err).toBeNull();
      expect(posts).toEqual([]);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('can save a post', (done) => {
    var post = new Post({ message: 'some message' });

    post.save((err) => {
      expect(err).toBeNull();

      Post.find((err, posts) => {
        expect(err).toBeNull();

        expect(posts[0]).toMatchObject({ message: 'some message' });
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  it('post has a timestamp', () => {
    const currentDate = new Date('2022-05-14T11:01:58.135Z');
    var post = new Post({ timestamp: currentDate });
    expect(post.timestamp).toEqual(currentDate);
  });

  // it('post can include an image', () => {
  //   const img = ?
  //   var post = new Post({ image: img });
  //   expect(post.image).toEqual(img);
  // });
});
```

Comment: I might be absolutely wrong, but I feel like you should not be testing mongoose schemas. It's essentially like testing mongoose itself and not your code. What you write in your schema is concrete and if it is not, there is nothing you can really do about it as it's mongoose's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended save the buffer of an image directly in the database. Instead, you can save the image in a CDN service (like Amazon S3) and save the URL of the image in the database. Consequently, this will help write your test, instead of buffering the image, you can just mock the image URL and check if the return is correct.

Comment: Just want to add that this does not have to be some payed service, you can just make upload and serve endpoint and store those images locally, as long as the app is private and no one can upload malware through it.

Comment: could I do store the image in a folder and then mock the folder filepath in my test rather than using an external service? e.g folder/image_name.png

Comment: @hibscodes There likely should not be a difference as both will deliver an image and the input props is location. But I don't see why would you test the mock of a code.